# What is the equivalent python code for this octave code

Tags: python-2.7, octave

[link to code and files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BycCBdaYJZilb09DQnNYRVJKM1E&usp=sharing)

```
1.I =imread('one.jpg');

2.I = inresize(I,[20,20]);
3.I=im2double(I);
4.I=mean(I,3);
#This next line
5.a = reshape(I,[],400);
```

I read an image and resizzed it to 20*20 and then converted it to matrix and then find the grayscale .All this I can do in Python too....but I can't do the 5 th line of code...if I tried ,
reshape (I,1,400)...the image appears rotated...I don't know how to write the 5 the line as above in python

## The problem

in the link along with the code theres is a displayData function.I saved the matrix i got using python as mat and loaded it on octave when i called displayData() on the matrix i got a rotated image.thats inclued in the link.And theres no such problem in octave.Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: As you are asking for help with your code, please provide a working code that you got so far.

Comment: I updated the answer according to the specific problem that you clarified with the update of your question. However, please read the following http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, to write a better question and a verifiable code, for now and the future. In summary, you should provide a small verifiable code and not attach a link to the whole project, as people should be able to easily test the code that gives error, and not waste time trying to understand the project.

Comment: I am sorry about that .I am new to this ,will try my best next time.

Comment: No problem, the important thing is that you learned ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reshaping an array you can use [numpy](http://numpy.org), and, following your code, you can use [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). In your case, you are changing the size of I, from (20,20) to (1,400). 
A complete example which saves the resulting reshaped array to a mat file, using [OpenCV](http://opencv.org) APIs for dealing with images, is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import scipy.io

I = cv2.imread('one.jpg')
I = cv2.resize(I,(20,20))
I = cv2.normalize(I.astype('float'), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
I = np.mean(I, axis=2)
a = np.reshape(I, (1,400), order='F')
scipy.io.savemat('a.mat', mdict={'a': a})
```

Note the second parameter of `reshape`, which is a tuple containing the new size of the array. Also, notice the third parameter `order` that allows to rearrange elements in column-major style (Fortran) which is the convention used by octave (see reshape in octave http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Rearranging-Matrices.html#XREFreshape). This results in a correct image, non rotated, compared to the one got from octave.

However, given the fact that you want to get from a 2d array a 1d array, you can use, from numpy, [`ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) if you want to get a view of I (when possible), namely a modification of `a` changes also `I`; or [`flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html), which returns a copy of `I`, thus modifying `a` does not change `I`. However, note that both `ravel` and `flatten` returns a 1d array resulting in a size of (400,). The same `order` parameter should be used.

Comment: I have added the link to code and the files.Thank you.